# Listview throwing error when using if in v-template

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

If I try to create conditions in my v-template like `if="transaction.id == 604"` I get the following error:

```
>System.err: Calling js method getView failed
System.err: 
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scopedFn' of undefined
```

If I set it to `if="transaction.id"` it works fine. transaction.id exists and it has a value of 604.

```
    <ListView for="transaction in transactions"  itemTap="onItemTap" height="80%" >
      <v-template if="transaction.id">
         <StackLayout>
            <Label :text="transaction.id" className="placeName" />
            <Label :text="transaction.amounttxt" className="placeName" />
            <Label :text="transaction.insight_text" className="placeName" />
          </StackLayout>
       </v-template>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one template with an `if` condition. There is no fallback template when the if condition fails. There should at least one template without `if` so it can be used when all your `if` conditions on other templates fail. Or at least one of you `if` should pass.

If you want to ignore any list item from being rendered, you should filter the array (`transactions`) itself.